# What's $\lim_{x \to -\infty} a^{\frac{x}{1-x}}$?

Tags: limits

Can someone hint me how to dertermine
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} a^{\frac{x}{1-x}}
\end{align}

where $a > 0$. L'Hospital?

Edit:
Whoops, actually I Need to evalute this thing
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (1 + a^{\frac{x}{1-x}})^{\frac{1-x}{x}}
\end{align}

Is this correct?
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (1 + a^{\frac{x}{1-x}})^{\frac{1-x}{x}} = 2^\infty
\end{align}

Comment: Could be done with L'Hospital, but it is really simpler than that.

Comment: x/1-x -> -1.  so a^(x/a-x) -> 1/a.  So 1 + a^foo -> 1 + 1/a.  So (1 + a^foo)^1/foo -> 1/(1 + 1/a) = a/(a + 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, one can easily do it without L'Hospital's rule as follows $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}a^{\frac{x}{1-x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}a^{\large \frac{1}{1/x-1}}$$
$$=a^{\large \frac{1}{0-1}}$$
$$=a^{-1}=\color{red}{\frac 1a}$$
where, $a>0$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{1-x}&=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(-1+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\\\
&=-1\
\end{align}$$ and $a^z$, $a>0$ is continuous.

Comment: I was unsure about $\frac{-\infty}{\infty} = -1$. How come?

Comment: Good question.  We have $$\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1/x-1}$$or $$\frac{x}{1-x}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: I thought this was too much of a giveaway. The op should figure out the limit $\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Comment: @Arbuja Notice the first comment/question that appears after this posted answer.  Clearly the OP was requesting more support and I wanted to help.  What is the objection?  ;-)) ... - Mark

Comment: Intuitively as x becomes large the magnitude of the x makes the 1 insignificant so x/(1-x) ~ x/-x = -1 should be the first guess.  Formally  As |x/(1-x) - (-1)| = |x/(1-x) + 1| = |(x + (1-x))/(1-x)| = |1/(1 -x)| < epsilon for x > 1 + 1/epsilon.

Comment: @fleablood What does this comment specifically address?  Do you believe that a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof is instructive here?

Comment: The OP asked how we know. $x/(1-x)$-> -1. That's how *I* know it.  Or we could use l'hopitals rule.  Or we could manipulate as you did.  If I'm not in a situation where I can't claim $x/(1-x)$ ->-1 as an obvious given, then, yes, I *do* believe a delta epsilon is instructive.  Why the heck wouldn't it be?  We *know* that $x/(1-x)$-> -1 because ... it's obvious... but if it isn't ... then, *yes*, a delta-epsilon proof is the 3,000 lb. elephant that clinches it unquestionably, formally, and irrevokably.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I agree that it would be instructive.  Would you like to post it?  It might "get lost" in a comment. - Mark

Comment: Other people have already answered this question thoroughly.  Not sure it needs more answers.